# How do I read a parquet in PySpark written from Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science-experience

I am using two Jupyter notebooks to do different things in an analysis.  In my Scala notebook, I write some of my cleaned data to parquet:

```
partitionedDF.select("noStopWords","lowerText","prediction").write.save("swift2d://xxxx.keystone/commentClusters.parquet")
```

I then go to my Python notebook to read in the data:

```
df = spark.read.load("swift2d://xxxx.keystone/commentClusters.parquet")
```

and I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for ParquetFormat at swift2d://RedditTextAnalysis.keystone/commentClusters.parquet. It must be specified manually;'
```

I have looked at the spark documentation and I don't think I should be required to specify a schema.  Has anyone run into something like this?  Should I be doing something else when I save/load?  The data is landing in Object Storage.

edit:
I'm sing spark 2.0 in both the read and the write.

edit2:
This was done in a project in Data Science Experience.

Comment: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jtyberg/9f8480724634c764d3c73c8e989fa8f9) to write/read a DataFrame as a parquet file to/from Swift.  It's using a simple schema (all "string" types).  What is the schema for your DataFrame?  Spark tries to infer the schema, but "Currently, numeric data types and string type are supported" (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery)

Comment: I believe you answered my question then!  The column "noStopWords" is a vector of words.  How do I save/load a df with this column?

Answer (score 66):

I use the following two ways to read the parquet file:

Initialize Spark Session:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('myAppName') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '5gb') \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "6") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

**Method 1:**

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet')
```

**Method 2:**

```py
sc = spark.sparkContext

# using SQLContext to read parquet file
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# read parquet file
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet')
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `parquet` format of Spark Session to read parquet files. Like this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("swift2d://xxxx.keystone/commentClusters.parquet")
```

Although, there is no difference between `parquet` and `load` functions. It might be the case that `load` is not able to infer the schema of data in the file (eg, some data type which is not identifiable by `load` or specific to `parquet`).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but this ended up with the same error.  I'll keep trying other things.

Comment: There is a tutorial for that here: http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/upload-files-to-ibm-data-science-experience-using-the-command-line-2/