# how to unnest a pandas column that its a string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a .parquet file that have below string column:

```
{"circuitStatus": "CREATED", "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:31.121Z",
"event": "CIRCUIT_CREATION"}, 
{"circuitStatus": "RUNNING", "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:32.147Z", 
"diff": [], "event": "CIRCUIT_UPDATED"}]}
```

I want to unnest this column but it's failing because it's a string.

this is the original dataframe:

[image]

and this is how I need it:
[image]

I manually did the unnest in my Jupyter Notebook with:

```
df =pd.concat([df.drop(['B'], axis=1), df['B'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

but only if the column is not a string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':'7e1ab727-a9e9-4c00-b6dc-9e65e91b9e4f','B':[{"circuitStatus": "CREATED", "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:31.121Z", "event": "CIRCUIT_CREATION"}, {"circuitStatus": "RUNNING", "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:32.147Z", "diff": [], "event": "CIRCUIT_UPDATED"}]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':'22222222-a9e9-4c00-b6dc-9e65e91b9e4f','B':[{"circuitStatus": "CREATED",` "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:31.121Z", "event": "CIRCUIT_CREATION"}, {"circuitStatus": "RUNNING", "startedAt": "2019-02-11T16:07:32.147Z", "diff": [], "event": "CIRCUIT_UPDATED"}]})
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
df3 =pd.concat([df3.drop(['B'], axis=1), df3['B'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df3
```

when I try the same code reading from the .parquet it doesn't throw an error but the unnest it's not done

Comment: You can use ```json.loads()``` (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json), but I would rather recommend just don't do ```parquet``` in ```pandas```. ```pyspark``` would spare you this kind of issues (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207794/11610186)