# Merge small parquet files into a single large parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory, parquet

I have been trying to merge small parquet files each with 10 k rows and for each set the number of small files will be 60-100. So resulting into around 600k rows minimum in the merged parquet file.

I have been trying to use pandas concat.it is working fine with around 10-15 small files merge.

But as the set may be consists of 50-100 files. The process it is getting killed while running python script with memory limit breached

So i am looking for a memory efficient way to merge any number of small parquet in range of 100 file set

Used pandas read parquet to read each individual dataframe and combine them with pd.conact(all dataframe)

Is there a better library other than pandas or if possible in pandas how it can be done efficiently.

Time is not constraint. It can run for some long time as well.

Comment: Have you tried using dask library instead of pandas? You can use `dd.read_parquet("path/to/files/*.parquet").compute().to_parquet('path/to/merged_file.parquet')` to read, merge and write to a file. Its supposed to be faster and memory efficient but I haven't tested the speed and memory.

Comment: Okay i will check it out

Comment: It didnt work out, it is even breaching higher limits then normal. I guess it is due to multiprocessing.

Comment: @ashyam I was surprised to find that dd.read_parquet reads only single-threaded from a local path (

Answer (score 6):

You can open files one by one and append them to the parquet file. Best to use pyarrow for this.

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

files = ["table1.parquet", "table2.parquet"]

schema = pq.ParquetFile(files[0]).schema_arrow
with pq.ParquetWriter("output.parquet", schema=schema) as writer:
    for file in files:
        writer.write_table(pq.read_table(file, schema=schema))
```

Comment: Thank you,this seems worked but even though the scheme is same it is throwing an exception
Value error: Table schema does not match schema used to create file
Table: 'column_indexes':[{"na"+ 58501 vs.

Comment: __index_level_0__: int64
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na' + 58501
__index_level_0__: int64
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na' + 58501 vs.

Coming like this between file and table

Comment: It looks like you files don't have have the same schema. It can happen if you generated the parquet files with pandas. It's not doing good job at guessing what the column types are. You can try to cast the data as you read it, but in practice it may be best to make sure the data you generate has got consistent schema.

Comment: It worked with slight modification in the read_table method by using same schema like this
writer.write_table(pq.read_table(file, schema=pq.ParquetFile(all_parquet_files[0]).schema_arrow))), It reduced the memory consumption to like 50%. Thank you. But my requirement is still need to reduce it like 80-90 percentage, I got 50 percent upto now.

Comment: You can try working at record batch level, using a ParquetFile (instead of pq.read_table). But if your files are small it's not going to make a big difference. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches

Comment: Given that Pandas is backed by pyarrow, why do you prefer this method to pd.read, pd.concat, pd.to_parquet?

Comment: pandas has only been backed by pyarrow since version `2.0.0`. Also this method only loads one file in memory at a time. If you call `pd.concat` you'd have to load every files in memory. They may not fit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299815/effectively-merge-big-parquet-files seems to indicate reading all the files in at once is the only way to get the performance improvement from aggregating Parquet files. Is this correct/has the situation changed?

Comment: I guess it depends what you are trying to optimise for. Memory usage of the concatenating job? Speed of the concatenating job? Optimal structure of the row group in the parquet file? This question is about memory. The question you are pointing out is about the size of the row group in the concatenated parquet file.

Comment: Isn't the main reason to merge Parquet files the performance benefit I mentioned (perhaps there are space considerations -- would we get them from the approach you outlined?)? The issue is that if I try to do the recommended (elsewhere) approach of reading in the files in Spark to achieve the recommended 1 GB on-disk size of the file, the uncompressed in-memory partition size can be ~ 2GB and crash the job (or even 1 GB and be extremely slow).

Comment: You may want to submit a new question because I don't think your use case relates to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Answering in Mar 2024, this is easy with the PyArrow `dataset` API (described in detail [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html)) which provides streaming capabilities to handle larger-than-memory files:

> The dataset API contains additional methods to read and process large amounts of data in a streaming fashion.

and

> If you are writing a large amount of data you may not be able to load everything into a single in-memory table. Fortunately, the write_dataset() method also accepts an iterable of record batches.

So merging a number of input files becomes as simple as:

```py
from pyarrow import dataset as ds

data = ds.dataset("data/input", format="parquet")

ds.write_dataset(
    data, 
    "data/output", 
    format="parquet",
    min_rows_per_group=25000,
    max_rows_per_file=5*10**6
)
```

Using `min_rows_per_group` ensures that you don't end up with too-small row-groups in your output (for example if your input is a number of tiny files), and you can also specify `max_rows_per_group` if you want tighter control on row-group size.

Using `max_rows_per_file` allows you to put an upper limit on your output file size.  Without it you end up with just one file, which could be very large depending on your input.

The [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html) for `write_dataset` has a lot more control options that you can explore.

One drawback (in my opinion) is that you can't define your control parameters in terms of *size*, only number of records (you can't for example say that you want your output files to be no more than 1GB each).  So if you want to use the simple code above as a generic parquet compactor utility you end up with varying results for different input data schemas.  I suppose you could scan the input dataset, determine some relationship between file size and records per row-group, and then apply that relationship when writing; but it would have been nice if the library did it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

For large data you should definitely use the PySpark library, split into smaller sizes if possible, and then use Pandas.
PySpark is very similar to Pandas.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991198/how-do-i-read-a-parquet-in-pyspark-written-from-spark)

Comment: Since we are writing a single large Parquet file, wouldn't there potentially be a problem with large partitions (e.g, > 1 GB in memory) for Spark?